# ArrayOutofBound Exception not caught

Tags: java, exception

Hi my code is generating an arrayoutofbound exception which is caught in the code but code terminates abruptly.I want the code to continue. Should an arrayoutofboundexception be caught by Exception or am i doing something wrong, please help catching the error .Exception is expected.Below is the code:-

```
try{
    CsgLogin=Ldap.getdomain(requesterLoginId);//This returns domain\usernmae
    LoginIDArray = CsgLogin.split("\\\\");
    requesterLoginId = LoginIDArray[1]; //Exception generated here

} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error in the GLDAP lookup or error in Domain Mapping");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

output:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at com.cs.ws.LdapConnect.getdomain(LdapConnect.java:131)
        at com.cs.ws.AgentConnector.startOfBreakGlass(AgentConnector.java:476)
        at com.cs.ws.AgentConnector.runBreakGlassProcess(AgentConnector.java:208)
        at com.cs.ws.MyAccessTimer.main(MyAccessTimer.java:93)
Error in the GLDAP lookup or error in Domain Mapping
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1768)
        at com.cs.ws.DomainMap.getDomain(DomainMap.java:21)
        at com.cs.ws.AgentConnector.startOfBreakGlass(AgentConnector.java:477)
        at com.cs.ws.AgentConnector.runBreakGlassProcess(AgentConnector.java:208)
        at com.cs.ws.MyAccessTimer.main(MyAccessTimer.java:93)
```

Comment: Can we see some output? (stacktrace)

Comment: Just as I thought -- it was caught. It's the other exception that isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` *is* being caught: you can tell by the fact that your message `Error in the GLDAP lookup or error in Domain Mapping` is printed. The first block that you are seeing is just what `printStackTrace()` produces.

The two aren't in order because one is printing to the standard output stream and the other is printing to the standard error stream.

The exception that is uncaught is the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` that is printed under your message.

Answer (score 1):

[`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is a subclass of `Exception` and should be caught there. There must be something else going on that isn't shown in your snippet. Please show at least the full method where the issue is stemming from. Also, please always include the stacktrace in a question about a thrown exception.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the ArrayOutOfBounds Exception when you are trying to access `LoginIDArray[1]` (i.e. the 2nd element), because `LoginIDArray` doesn't have a second element.

Which means your call to `Split("\\\\")` isn't finding any `"\\"` to split by (two escaped backslashes). `CSGLogin` doesn't contain two backslashes, it has one.

so, change your Split string to `"\\"`

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`, so it's unchecked - meaning that you don't have to explicitly catch it or declare it. In a well-written code it shouldn't be necessary to catch it; surely you have an index error somewhere that's causing the exception.